# Why is the prefix 'Ani'(And) used in the title of Dr. Kashinath Ghanekar biopic?

Tags: title, ani-dr-kashinath-ghanekar

*Ani... Dr. Kashinath Ghanekar* (And ... Dr. Kashinath Ghanekar) is a recently released Marathi (language) biopic movie about the life of legendary theater & movie superstar (in-fact, Marathi industry's first).

Given that he was the first superstar of this regional film & theater industry, who was also a little egotistical & critical of his rival actors, I was curious as to why his biopic is prefixed with 'Ani'(and) making it appear like it's a film about something and Dr. Kashinath Ghanekar instead of just being about him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's how he was named in his later plays:

> Title of the film Aani Dr Kashinath Ghanekar. Has a interesting story. Dr Kashinath Ghanekar's name would be taken on the stage after everyone's name was announced. Those days legendary Hindi actor Pran had started doing character roles and he would be credited in films as And Pran. His future wife Kanchan taught he should also go for something like this.In his later plays when he opted for this experiment his fans would be waiting in the hall to hear his name and hall would be filled with noise of whistles and claps. - [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8784906/trivia?item=tr4264443)